# Chess game viewer plugin for wordpress

Tags: software

Do you know of any PGN/game viewer for Wordpress, which can be used to generate diagrams, and chess games?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/rpb-chessboard/

Comment: Also - https://wordpress.org/plugins/embed-chessboard/

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple.  The most popular is likely [Embed Chessboard](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/embed-chessboard/).  The nice thing about it is that the tags are simply PGN references:

> [pgn parameter=value ...]
>   ... chess games in PGN format ...
>   [/pgn]

So if you're already familiar with PGN, put it into your Wordpress page and the plugin detects it..

Would you share your Wordpress site URL in comments once complete?

Comment: This one is based on `pgn4web` which I used extensively to embed chess games in my chess forum. Great tool, and great support from the developer (Paulo).

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of dhtmlchess.com. I have created a plugin for Wordpress which is available at

http://wordpresschess.com/

It supports the [fen] and [pgn] tags, and also a [chess] tag for games stored in a database. It also comes with an online game editor which makes it possible to create, analyse and edit games online.

It also lets you import PGN games and have them stored in a database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rpb-chessboard/) plug-in called RPB chessboard (hat tip to @GloriaVictus in the comments).

Installing the plug in allows PGN and FEN to be added using the `[pgn] ... [/pgn]` and `[fen] ... [/fen]` tags.

Answer (score -1):

See [this](http://pgn4web.casaschi.net/demo.html) website here, and also a [test](http://pgn4web-test.casaschi.net/wordpress/).